# How to use MIN function in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, min

This is the query:-

```
select id, min(param_value) from table1;
```

but it gives me error : `NOT A SINGLE-GROUP GROUP FUNCTION.`

plz help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
SELECT id, MIN(param_value) 
FROM table1
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the ID (or perhaps multiple IDs) with the mininum param_value then you need something like:-

```
select id, param_value 
from table1 
where param_value = (select min (param_value) from table1);
```

Comment: select * from ( select id,formula for distance as distance from table1)x where distance=(select min(distance)from table1...this is my query  bt it is giving me all the records rather than just one id having minimum distance...plz help me with this...